# Disambiguate [hive] and/or burninate [hivedb]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

Hive, nowadays, has two meanings:

1. > database built on top of Hadoop and facilitates easy data
   > summarization, ad-hoc queries, and the analysis of large datasets
   > stored in Hadoop compatible distributed file system (...)

   [Current description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hive).
2. > Key-value database written in pure Dart.

   [GitHub repository](https://github.com/hivedb/hive).

`[hive]` already has a synonym, `[apache-hive]`.

For Dart's meaning, there is another tag, [hivedb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hivedb), with only <del>three</del> five questions, which also tends to be confusing, since both are databases.

Dart's Hive is often used for applications made with Flutter; there are [<del>51</del> 70 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hive+flutter) tagged with `[hive]` and `[flutter]`, and [<del>98</del> 132 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhive%5D%20flutter) for *flutter* tagged with `[hive]`.

Should `[hivedb]` be burninated, or renamed as `[hive-dart]` or `[hive-flutter]`? What about `[hive]`?

Comment: Punny opportunities: [hive mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_mind_(science_fiction)) and [a StarCraft reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Races_of_StarCraft#Zerg_factions)

Comment: The problem is more diffult probably because there are many other Apache-Hive related tags: hiveql, hiveddl, hive-partitions, hive-serde, hiveserver2, hive-query,  hive-configuration, etc etc. Can we add bigdata- preffix to all these tags including hive? Bigdata is the most significant difference between these databases IMO

Comment: big data? don't you get bug data from a hive?

Comment: @MattEllen Bug or not bug, but Hive is being widely used in bigdata world.

Comment: @leftjoin Yes, that's why it's difficult to make decisions about it, IMO. Hive (Apache) is very popular in Big Data, and Hive (Flutter) is increasing in popularity

Comment: I was not able to reach Aache-Hive pmc. And this is getting worse. there are many new questions about flutter hive tagged hive.

Comment: @leftjoin Fixing my previous comment (now deleted): previously the tag [apache-hive] had already redirected to [hive]. But yes, it's really messy.

Comment: flutter-hive is good solution.https://stackoverflow.com/q/65452094/2700344 Maybe they need few more specific tags like dart-hive or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In early December 2020, the [flutter-hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-hive) tag was created (thanks @leftjoin for the comment).
I don't know if that is the ultimate solution (instead of a tag like *dart-hive*) but, for the moment, it is a good alternative.